# Activity buttons click not working after adding navigation drawer into my activity

Tags: android, xml

As m having a map activity.. except from the floating button no other button or text field is working on clicking.. map zvoom in zoom out or scroll nothing working. here is my code

content_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.ravi.poison.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/select_dialog_item_material"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/bitch">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="281dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/searchloc"
        android:layout_weight="1.03" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view" />

        <!--
            android:background="@drawable/blue"
            -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bitch"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:id="@+id/cotxt"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cofnd"
            android:text="Get lat lon"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/map"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/map" />

    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.ravi.poison.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    <include layout="@layout/nav_drawer"/>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

nav_drawer.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentholder"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navlist"
        android:background="#dedede"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </ListView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ravi.poison;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.audiofx.BassBoost;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.jar.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView cotxt;
    Button cobtn;
    double lat = 0;
    double lon = 0;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    LatLng longi = new LatLng(23.345367, 172.1243254);
    private GoogleMap map;


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cotxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cotxt);
        cobtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cofnd);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.clear();
        //map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(longi).title("Surry"));
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                cotxt.setText(location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude());
                lon = location.getLongitude();
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                longi = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(longi).title("Hey there! I am using whatsapp :v"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };
        configureButton();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(longi, 17);
                map.animateCamera(cu);
                Snackbar.make(view, "Go fun yourself", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });



    }

    private void configureButton() {
        cobtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What should i do?

Comment: try to put the setonclicklistener inside the onCreate()

Comment: Don't forget `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: Bro not even map zoom in zoom out or scroll working

Comment: did you solve the problem?